On the Discriminant and Preparation of Multivariate Polynomials
We know that the discriminant of a polynomial
$$
f(x) = y^n + a_1(x_1, \dots, x_e) y^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n(x_1, \dots, x_e) \in k[x_1, \dots, x_e][y]
$$
can be expressed as
$$
\sum_{p \geq a} u_p(x_1, \dots, x_e),
$$
where $a = \inf \{ d \mid u_d \neq 0 \}$, and $u_p$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $p$.
Now, consider the following definition:

The polynomial $f$ is called prepared if and only if $u_a = c_a x_1^a + u'_a$, where $c_a$ is a constant and $u'_a$ is homogeneous of degree $a$.

How can we make a change of variables of a prepared polynomial so that the new polynomial has a discriminant equal to
$$
c_a x_1^{p_1} \cdots x_e^{p_e}
$$
for some $(p_1, \dots, p_e) \in \mathbb{N}^e$?
